# Hover html form input over an image

Tags: css, image, forms, input, hover

I currently have a simple form with a text input that has a blue background set by css. It all works perfectly and looks good in firefox and ie but not on an iPhone or safari? How can I arrange it so that there is an image behind the input rather than a background?
Please note, there are other images either end of the input, see - http://stack.uk.to

Comment: Is the input box not larger than the end images? It is on mine?

Comment: The input is very slightly shorter, but I had to zoom way in to notice.  And that may be the zoom offsetting it.

Comment: Oh right, is there any solution you could help me with for the question of replacing the colour with an image?

Comment: Specify a background image instead of just a background color...

Comment: On an iphone, it rounds the corners and doesn't look flush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I see is that the CSS for your input says its `height` should be `48px`.  Your images that sit next to it are `50px` in `height`.  If you change the `input`'s height to `50px` it seems to match.

style.css:

```
.loginInput {
    margin-right: -11px;
    background: #0099FF;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000066;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: 'Cubano', Arial, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 50px; 
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: I did use this thanks, but i eventually removed the rounded edges on apple products and relaligned everything.